# How to mimic the feedback of a ListView

Tags: android

Is there a simple way (property?) to mimic the touch feedback of a `ListView` item on any other view, for example a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: You mean the vibrator feedback?

Comment: No, the visual feedback i.e. the blue highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Use [android:listSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector):

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_sel"
```

In your drawable folder, put list_sel:

**list_sel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_sel" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_sel" />
</selector>
```

**list_bg**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient 
        android:startColor="#77000000"
        android:centerColor="#88000000"
        android:endColor="#99000000"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

In my case, `list_bg_sel` is an image, but you can create using shape as well.